iCal events show the start time as both the start and end time in the notification center
I have my uni calendar linked on my Ubuntu install, however, in the calendar preview, events from iCal calendars show their start and end time as the start time, despite the entries being correct in the calendar. Normal calendar events show up with the correct end time, so I'm not sure what's going on here.
Is this a bug, or a misconfiguration on my part?
 
